# Repair TFS Server Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I use a server workspace for my Visual Studio / TFS setup because our project far exceeds the 100,000 file recommended limit for local workspaces.

One of the drawbacks of a server workspace is that Visual Studio cannot automatically detect changes to files in the workspace if these changes have been made outside of Visual Studio.

If I believe there may be undetected changes lurking in my workspace, how can I tell Visual Studio to actively/explicitly check the integrity of the workspace.  I.E. I need a "get" operation that assumes that zero pending changes may actually be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PowerTools command tfpt online which looks for files which have had their read-only attribute removed (if you were messing with them on the train home for example) but I guess you might have new files and need something like detected changes in local workspaces.

If you go into Source Control explorer you can right click your folder, select compare and then play around with what you need to compare the server to your local copy (file types, new files, different files etc)
[image: Compare]

TFPT Online:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/11/16/power-toy-tfpt-exe.aspx

Comment: This command has been deprecated and you should use "tf reconcile" instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TFS 2013+ and Visual Studio 2013+ then you can use the "tf reconcile" command to analyse the differences.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385984.aspx

The power tools "tfpt online" command has been depricated for some time.